# Profit on sales

Tags: probability

It is estimated that if Angela buys the Key King machine she has a 60% chance of selling 1,500 key rings per month and a 40% chance of selling 800 per month. If she purchases the Fancy Fob system she has a 45% chance of selling 1,200 key rings per month and a 55% chance of selling 700 per month.

She would sell the Key King rings for $\$3.00$ each or the Fancy Fob rings for $\$5.00$ each.

Which would be more profitable?

Comment: Could you add your attempt?

Comment: You must also know there is no information on profits, unless one assumes everything has equal profit margins or something similar.  Perhaps the question is which would lead to larger expected sales value.

Answer (score 0):

Average month selling of keys from Key King machine: $0.6\cdot 1500 + 0.4 \cdot 800 = 1100$

Average month selling of keys from Fancy Fob system is: $0.45\cdot 1200 + 0.55\cdot 700 = 925$

Average month profit from Key King machine is: $1100\cdot 3 = \textbf{3300}$

Average month profit from Fancy Fob system is: $925\cdot 5 = \textbf{4625}$

Fancy Fob system would be more profitable.